# inserting Object that contains array into return JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I know it sounds bizarre, but the reason being is to make my JSON work with [Faux-3D Shaded Globe](http://bl.ocks.org/dwtkns/4686432)

I am calling Instagrams endpoint API and i get the following data that gets put into a JSON:

Name, longitude, latitude

my question is: how do i make an another JSON object within my original JSON object that will hold an array with the longitude and latitude?

This is the ideal return JSON i would like

```
Features: Array[size]
  Object:
     properties:Object:
     geometry: Object:
               coordinates: array[2]
```

this is my attempt

```
complete: function(data){
      var geoArray = data.map(function(item){
          tempJSON = {};
          geometry = new Object();
          var coordinates = []
          if(item.location === null){
            console.log("null check");
          }
          else{
            tempJSON.name = item.location.name;
            geometry = coordinates.push(item.location.latitude,item.location.longitude);
            tempJSON.geometry = geometry;
            // tempJSON.geometry[1] = item.location.longitude;
          }
        return tempJSON;
      });
      return res.json({features: geoArray});
    }
  });
```

right now my it returns geometry as geomtry:2 when i check the chrome console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating (and discarding) an object named `geometry`, and replacing it with an array (or trying to - `push()` returns the *count* of items in an array, not the array itself), which is then just assigned to a member of `tempJSON`.  Skip the intermediate variables:

```
var geoArray = data.map(function(item){
    tempJSON = {};

    if (item.location === null){
      console.log("null check");
    }
    else {
      tempJSON.name = item.location.name;
      tempJSON.geometry = {
        coordinates: [item.location.latitude, item.location.longitude]
      };
    }

    return tempJSON;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I need geometry to be a Object type, and it will hold an array called coordinates. Is this doable? right now it makes geometry the array itself.

Comment: Yep. Edited to do just that.